# How to print only Category column[no other columns]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to access the Category in given dataframe but not able to get it. "How to print only category column?"

This code shows that there is only one column in counts but i want to access Category too which is used to groupby the data.

[image]

Comment: You can iterate over `counts` using a `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use the get_group method:

```
In [21]: gb.get_group('foo')
Out[21]: 
     A         B   C
0  foo  1.624345   5
2  foo -0.528172  11
4  foo  0.865408  14
```

Note: This doesn't require creating an intermediary dictionary / copy of every subdataframe for every group, so will be much more memory-efficient that creating the naive dictionary with dict(iter(gb)). This is because it uses data-structures already available in the groupby object.

You can select different columns using the groupby slicing:

```
In [22]: gb[["A", "B"]].get_group("foo")
Out[22]:
     A         B
0  foo  1.624345
2  foo -0.528172
4  foo  0.865408

In [23]: gb["C"].get_group("foo")
Out[23]:
0     5
2    11
4    14
Name: C, dtype: int64
```